# installing pyspark on windows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I can do a `pip install pyspark` on my windows. When I try to run a sample script below it tells me my `SPARK_HOME` is not set.

Do i need to set my SPARK_HOME still and how do I go about doing it?

The blogs which I have referred online do a manual extraction of the spark files from the spark website and then later they have to put the SPARK_HOME and the PYTHONPATH.

However, I thought this was elimated with `pip install pyspark`.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.sql('''select 'spark' as hello ''')
df.show()
```

For intellij, do I still need to do additional configuration once i have installed in pyspark and set up as necessary?

Answer (score 1):

In 2022, this worked for me. My setup was jupyter notebook in VS Code.

Prereq:

- Ensure JDK 1.8
- Download repo zip from: https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils

  - Extract out hadoop version files of your choice (my ver: 3.0.0)
  - Place files in a some folder e.g. c:\blah\hadoop\bin  (bin folder is required)

```
#!java -version         # check your java version
!pip install pyspark

hadoopFilesPath = r"c:\blah\hadoop"
import os
os.environ["HADOOP_HOME"] = hadoopFilesPath
os.environ["hadoop.home.dir"] = hadoopFilesPath
os.environ["PATH"] = os.environ["PATH"] + f";{hadoopFilesPath}\\bin"

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').getOrCreate()
print(spark.version)

df = spark.read.csv("test.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)
df.show()

df.write.parquet(r"C:\blah\data\test.parquet")
```

Note that the environment variables do the trick. Without the, First two are obvious (part of error message), the path one required googling.

Relevant error messages:

- java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
- Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.parquet.
- java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
- InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand windows An error occurred while calling Py4JJavaError

Comment: Ideally, you use Java 11, or the higher version that Spark supports

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you do not need a full Spark installation, it is recommended that you just install it in your environment with pip:

```
pip install pyspark
```

If you are using conda, you may get it with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyspark
```

Once the installation is ready, you should be able to invoke Spark shell with the `pyspark` keyword.
There are a couple of issues that you may encounter while running the executable. Notably, you may face following error:

> Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store

Obviously, if you have just installed PySpark, you have Python ready in your virtual environment, so you can turn off these default paths by disabling `python.exe` and `python3.exe` App Installers in `Apps >> Apps & features >> App execution aliases` in Settings.

You may still face a seemingly related error:

> Missing Python executable `python3`, defaulting to `[path_to_spark_home]` for `SPARK_HOME` environment variable. Please install Python or specify the correct Python executable in `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` or `PYSPARK_PYTHON` environment variable to detect `SPARK_HOME` safely.

This error message be coupled with a few of those:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

In this case, the issue could either be in inappropriate `SPARK_HOME` variable or an unspecified Python path.

In the first case, try setting `SPARK_HOME` explicitly:

```
$env:SPARK_HOME=python -c "import pyspark, pathlib; print(pathlib.Path(pyspark.__file__).parent)"
```

Additionally, if you are still facing issues while running pyspark, such as:

> Cannot run program "python3": [...] The system cannot find the file specified

set Python-related variables to Python path in your environment. Specifically:

```
$env:PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
$env:PYSPARK_PYTHON=python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

If you do not have **Java 11** installed, you should [download](https://files02.tchspt.com/temp/jdk-11.0.14_windows-x64_bin.exe), install it and set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to the path, where it was installed. If you are using conda, you may use OpenJDK instead:

```
conda install -c conda-forge openjdk
```

You may still face an error stating:

> Did not find winutils.exe. java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset.

As expected, you need to [download binaries](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils) for Hadoop and then set the `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable to that path.

Once all these paths are specified, PySpark executable should be able to run as long as you have necessary permissions.

Try testing its capability after running `pyspark` with a simple script:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Spark", "Impala"), ("3.2", "2.2")])
df.show()
```